# what is @noop in simulacrum in Cats

Tags: scala, scala-cats

what is @noop annotation for cats. Basically, it doesnt accept any String alias like @op. This is scala doc for it

```
/**
 * Annotation that may be applied to methods on a type that is annotated with `@typeclass`.
 *
 * Doing so results in the method being excluded from the generated syntax ops type.
 */
class noop() extends StaticAnnotation
```

I am confused about this documentation. Can someone explain to me and also give me an example about how to use it ?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so lets say you have this typeclass:

```
@typeclass trait Foo[A] {
     def bar(x: A)(y: A): A
}
```

you would then be able (via implicit syntax defined by simulacrum), be able to write this method:

```
def baz[A: Foo](x: A, y: A): A = x bar y
```

if you were to instead annotate the `bar` method with `@noop`, The above would not compile saying something like "bar is not a member of type A", because there wouldn't be an implicit conversion provided from A to something that has a bar method.